# find entropy and mutual information

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Let $X_1, X_2$ i.i.d. from $\text{Binom}(1, \frac{1}{2})$. Let $Y=\max(X_1, X_2)$. How can we obtain the following quantities?

1) $H(Y)$

2) $I(X_1; Y)$

3) $I(X_1, X_2; Y)$

$H$ is entropy, $I$ is mutual information.

Comment: What is $b()$? State your question clearly and say what you have tried.

Comment: This time I have editted the question for you. Next time care to write down everything carefully and explain what you have tried so that a useful discussion is possible here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_1$, $X_2$ are both Bernoulli with $p$, we have:
$$
P(Y=0)=P(X_1=0)P(X_2=0)=(1-p)^2\implies P(X=1)=1-(1-p)^2
$$
The entropy of $Y$ would be easy to find from here:

> $$
> H(Y)=-(1-p)^2\log(1-p)^2-(2p-p^2)\log(2p-p^2).
> $$

This corrsponds to a channel with the following relation:
$$
Y=X_1+X_2-X_1X_2.
$$
In any case, $Y$ is a function of $X_1,X_2$: $H(Y|X_1,X_2)=0$. Hence:

> $$
> I(X_1,X_2;Y)=H(Y).
> $$

Finally if $X_1=1$ then $Y=1$ so:
$$
H(Y|X_1=1)=0.
$$
and if $X_1=0$, then $Y=X_2$. So:
$$
H(Y|X_1=0)=H(X_2).
$$
In other words:

> $$
> I(X_1;Y)=H(Y)-P(X_1=0)H(X_2).
> $$

If $p=\frac 12$, $H(Y)=\frac 14\log 4+\frac 34\log \frac 43$ and $H(X_2)=1$. (Base of logarithm is 2.)